# How to round a decimal point up?

Tags: c#, math

I am trying to dynamically determine the max value for a chart. If i am inspecting a value of

> .434

I need this to round up to the

> .5

.

It seems pretty simple and maybe I am overlooking some part of this but i have tried a couple different approaches with underwhelming success. Does anyone know how to always round up with decimal places ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
double x = 0.434;
int y = (int)Math.Ceiling(x*10);
x = y/10.0;
```

Comment: Yup, I didn't catch that the rounding is to the right of the decimal place.